# Incompatible types Object cannot be converted into Throwable?

Tags: java

Throwable is a sub class of Object. According to polymorphism in java a super class reference variable and hold object of any of its sub class.Then why is happen in my pc?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUdbW.png)

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
class ExceptionHandlingEx1{

public static void main(String[] args){

try{
out.println("Try Block Executed");

out.println(5/0);
out.println("After AE");
}
catch(ArithmeticException a){
out.println("Exception Success");
try{throw new NumberFormatException();}

catch(Object c){

out.println("RTE(NFE) Success ");
}

finally{
out.println("Finally From Catch");
}
}
finally{
out.println("Finally Block Executed");

}
out.println("Program Terminated Success");
}
}
```

Comment: I guess your problem is the other way around. Can you show your code?

Comment: import static java.lang.System.*;
class ExceptionHandlingEx1{

public static void main(String[] args){

try{
out.println("Try Block Executed");

out.println(5/0);
out.println("After AE");
}
catch(ArithmeticException a){
out.println("Exception Success");
try{throw new NumberFormatException();}

catch(Object c){

out.println("RTE(NFE) Success ");
}

finally{
out.println("Finally From Catch");
}
}
finally{
out.println("Finally Block Executed");

}
out.println("Program Terminated Success");
}
}

Comment: put code in the question please. Why would you even think to do otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `Throwable` is a class extends `Object`, so a `Throwable` can be converted as `Object`, but never the opposite

Comment: Throwable is a class.

Comment: I just edit my answer to take in consideration your remarks